# How to make center the author names and put the institute and date in bottom of slide in beamer?

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, slideshow

I want to make a slide. I make code as below.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, 10pt,notheorems]{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Red]{structure}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definisi}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\title[]{TITLE}

\author[]{{\textbf{by:}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Author 1
            \item Author 2
            \item Author 3
        \end{enumerate} 
    \end{center}
}}
\vfill
\institute{{DEPARTMENT OF MATHEMATICS\\ABC UNIVERSITY\\CITY}
    \date{}
}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And the result is

[image]

Why the `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` and `\vfill` is not working?

I want make title page as this picture.

[image]

So, how to make center the author names and put the institute and date in bottom of slide?

Answer (score 1):

For centering you may use just \centering

```
\begin{enumerate}
        \centering
        \item Author 1
        \item Author 2
        \item Author 3
\end{enumerate}
```